# File Transfer failed

Tags: filezilla

I have ftp server in my local machine using MFT Internet Server. I am trying to upload / download the files from the MFT Internet server.

I could not transfer files from fileZilla to MFT Internet Server. It says

Status: Starting upload of C:\fileZilla\Rs.766Transferred.jpg
Command:    PASV
Response:   227 Entering Passive Mode (10,231,0,108,7,138)
Command:    STOR Rs.766Transferred.jpg
Response:   150 Opening data connection for transferdirectory
Response:   426 Transfer failed. AuditID=A70420000444
Error:  File transfer failed

I could not find any solution for the above. Please help me to fix this.

-Sridhar

Answer (score 1):

The FTP server answers with an FTP error code (error 426). I never have seen "AuditID" before, so it might be some special (error) code your FTP server is trying to tell you. Check the FTP server documentation.

A quick Internet search lead to the [TIBCO MFT Internet Server User Guide](https://docs.tibco.com/pub/managed-file-transfer-internet-server/7.2.0-may-2012/MFT%20IS%20v7.2.0%20User%20Guide.pdf), which refers to "AuditID" in section 3.3.4.2.1 (page 101). I have no idea about their concept of branching and FTP transfers, so I leave you alone there. Hope it helped.